# Gnuplot timefmt - need full using spec

Tags: gnuplot

Cant' fit a function to time data in Gnuplot 4.7. What gives?

```
set xdata time;
set timefmt "%Y %m %d %H:%M"
set format x "%d %Hh" 
set xtics 43200
f(x)=M + V*sin(pi*x/43200.0-P); M=24;V=7.0;P=2.0;
fit f(x) '2013-06-Pisa.dat' using 1:6 via M, V, P
                                      ^
Need full using spec for time data
```

Note that the following works just fine:

```
plot '2013-06-Pisa.dat' usi 1:6 w lp pt 7 lc 1, f(x)
```

Contents of 2013-06-Pisa.dat data:

```
2013 06 17 02:15        1017    16      93      ESE-4   Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 02:45        1017    16      93      SE-5    Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 03:45        1017    16      93      SE-2    Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 04:15        1017    16      87      SE-2    Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 04:45        1017    16      87      ESE-3   Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 05:15        1017    17      88      ESE-4   Buona   Sereno  -
2013 06 17 05:45        1017    17      88      SE-5    Buona   Sereno  -
...
```

A similar issue: the same error message when plotting inline data like so:

```
set timefmt "%Y %m %d"
plot 'othertimedata.dat' usi 1:4 w lp pt 7 lc 1, '-' usi 1:2 w l
'2013 06 17' 28
'2013 06 18' 30
'2013 06 19' 32
e
```

Comment: I can confirm this error with the current development version. Since 4.6 the fitting code was thourougly changed, so that I'm not sure if this is a bug, or what could be missing. I filed a bug report [#1424 Fitting with time data doesn't work](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1424/). Regarding your last script, this works fine if you use `'-' using 1:4 w l` and drop the quotes around the inline time data.

Comment: That seems to be fixed in the current CVS version, see the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that in my question I used an incorrect `fit` statement (inferred  -- alas -- from old gnuplot posts and possibly from a dated manual) Here is the corrected one (thanks to 
[Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604213/christoph)'s [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1424/))

```
fit f(x) '2013-06-Pisa.dat' using 1:6:(1.0) via M, V, P
```